# The null of a product of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused when I need to find the null of a product of linear maps

$(ST)(v)$ , where $S \in L(V,W) $ and $T \in L(U,V)$

Is the nullST = to all the elements of U that it sends to zero or also the elements of V that S sends to zero?
I ask this question in the context of linear algebra. How do you guys see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition $ST$ is a linear map $U \to W$, so its nullspace is by definition a subspace of $U$. Specifically,
$$\mathrm{Null}(ST) = \{u \in U \mid S(T(u)) = 0\}.$$

Comment: OWhhhhh so all the u's that get mapped to the nullspace of S